# how to read numbers from a file and assign them to what they actually mean

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

Write a C program to

1. calculate the mean level of E. Coli bacteria for a series of lake beaches in Ontario
2. make a decision to open or close the beach
3. produce a report for all the lakes and beaches contained in the data file.

For each beach, there is a line of data in the file with the following fields separated by blanks - lake ID (integer), beach number (integer), number of samplings (integer) and one real number (double) per sampling representing the number of organisms in 100ml of water.

Lake table

```
1: Ontario        
2: Erie    
3: Huron       
4: Muskoka   
5: Simcoe
```

Beach table

```
100: Kew Beach       
101: Sunnyside Beach  
103: Sandbanks   
201: Port Dover  
202: Port Burwell  
203: Crystal Beach   
301: Goderich  
302: Sauble Beach    
303: Kincardine   
401: Muskoka Beach   
501: Sibbald Point
```

this is the file data:

```
1 100 12 47.7 52.2 45.5 78.7 45.5 33.2 50.4 60.2 48.9 43.3 49.9 50.6     
1 101 9 75.5 53.2 65.1 81.1 44.1 42.2 41.1 39.7 51.1      
2 201 3 56.6 49.7 45.5     
2 202 2 44.4 66.6          
5 501 4 55.5 34.4 66.6 22.2     
4 401 4 33.3 44.4 55.5 66.6        
3 301 3 50.0 51.1 49.8       
3 302 4 77.7 66.6 22.2 33.3      
3 303 3 55.5 55.5 44.0      
1 103 1 13.3
```

i know how to write the code, the statements but what i dont know is how to make the program read the file and how will i assign that THAT specific number is lake ontario or, how to get the program to average the samples,
I am just 2 months into programming for the first time so please bear with me.

Comment: This would much simpler by  using a SQL database

Comment: Please don't post your homework questions here, without showing any _relevant_ efforts. This has a high probability of getting closed.

Comment: Since you wrote "I know how to write the code", please show what you have done so far and clearly point out the piece where you have a problem with and what you tried so far. This will highly increase the chance you will get help.

Comment: I am not asking anyone to do my homework for me. That would be very stupid since I have to give an exam as well and then I won't have stackoverflow.com over there to help me.I am asking for help on topics which my instructor has not yet taught, but assigned the due date very early for this so I want to have a head start on it . For me to actually start writing the program I need to know how to import the data from the file, and then make the program use that data. that is what I am asking

Answer (score 0):

You can write block structs at files, to save the data in binary.

For Create structs

```
struct Lake_table {
    int id;
    char name[length];
};

struct Beach_table {
    int samplings;
    char name[length]
    double samplings_ml;

};
```

Initialize the structs with the data that way !

```
struct Lake_table lakes[] =  {
{1,"Ontario"}
{2,"Erie"}
{3,"Huron"}
{4,"Muskoka"}
{5,"Simcoe"}
};

struct Beach_table beaches[] = {
{100,"Kew Beach",0.0}
{101,"Sunnyside Beach",0.0}
{103,"Sandbanks",0.0}
{201,"Port Dover",0.0}
{202,"Port Burwell",0.0}
{203,"Crystal Beach",0.0}
{301,"Goderich",0.0}
{302,"Sauble Beach",0.0}
{303,"Kincardine",0.0}
{401,"Muskoka Beach",0.0}
{501,"Sibbald Point",0.0}
};
```

To save your struct do it !

```
FILE *file;
const char file_name[] =  "filename.dat";
file = fopen(file_name,"wb");
if (file != EOF) {
    fwrite(beaches,sizeof(struct Beach_table),length,file);

}
```

To get your struct do it !

```
struct Beach_table beaches;
FILE *file;
    const char file_name[] =  "filename.dat";
    file = fopen(file_name,"rb");
    if (file != EOF) {
        fread(beaches,sizeof(struct Beach_table),length,file);
    }
```

To access the data, the concept is the same as arrays, pointer. Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much for actually writing all that but I think that's advanced level stuff, which I have no idea how to use